# "0: command not found". Scp not working

Tags: ubuntu, scp

I'm trying to transfer a file from a remote host (Ubuntu 14.04) to a local host (Ubuntu 16.04) via scp:

```
scp user@server:path-to-file path-to-file
```

The result is as follows, however no file appears on my host computer:

```
file.php                        100%  654KB 653.6KB/s   00:00
```

I then enter $?, and it returns:

```
0: command not found
```

I have openssh-client installed on both the host and remote, and they are both in the /usr/bin folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By typing

```
$?
```

the expansion of the variable `$?` is done and tried to interpret as a command. Because the scp did not fail the return code is 0 and thus `$?` expands to  `0`.

So you could have been typing

```
0
```

Unless there is a command calles `0` in your path this will fail.

Perhaps you meant to type

```
echo $?
```

to print out the exit code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mixed up the scp command, and instead of doing it on the local host, was executing it on the remote host. Therefore I feel this question should be deleted.